# This overload of the method 'System.String.Split' is currently not supported

Tags: c#, lambda, split

I'm using Split in an expression in .NET. I get next error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression 'e.Languages.Split(,, None)': This overload of the method 'System.String.Split' is currently not supported.
```

I had to overload the method, because if I don't I get next error:

```
An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments.
```

Is it not possible to use split in an expression?

The Code:

```
public static Expression<Func<CompanyEntity, CompanyDto>> DbMapping()
{
    return comp => new CompanyDto
    {
        Id = comp.CompanyID,
        Languages = comp.Languages.Split(',',StringSplitOptions.None).Select(l => l.Trim()).ToList(),
    };
}
```

How it is used:

```
var company = await _dbContext.CompanyEntity
    .Where(comp => comp.CompanyID == companyId)
    .Select(Company.DbMapping())
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Please show relevant code too

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database cannot do the `Split`. Do it after retrieval instead:

```
var companyEntity = await _dbContext.CompanyEntity
    .Where(comp => comp.CompanyID == companyId)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
if(companyEntity!=null){
    var company = Company.DbMapping(companyEntity);
    //etc
}
```

And change `DbMapping` to drop the `Expression` and `Func` stuff, just accepting the entity and returning the DTO.

```
public static CompanyDto DbMapping(CompanyEntity comp)
{
    return new CompanyDto
    {
        Id = comp.CompanyID,
        Languages = comp.Languages.Split(',',StringSplitOptions.None).Select(l => l.Trim()).ToList(),
    };
}
```

---

Insert standard warnings about how comma-delimited strings aren't a sensible way of storing multiple values in a database. There are types *designed* for storing multiple values - tables, JSON and XML; I'd much rather see you use one and not have to do this string processing *at all*.